# In C++, do ref-qualifiers express a form of subtyping?

Tags: c++, reference, type-systems, qualifiers, subtyping

From a programming language theory standpoint, in C++, qualifiers like `const` and `volatile` allow to express a form of subtyping, with for example `int` being a subtype of `const int`.

I was wondering if we could also consider that ref-qualifiers `&` and `&&` allow to express a form of subtyping or not. In other words, can we consider that `T`, `T&` and `T&&` are related by a subtyping relationship or not, from a programming language theory standpoint? And if so, what is this relationship?

Comment: I wouldn't think of references as types, but as aliases.  In theory they don't really exist, they are just a new name for some object.

Comment: Surely const objects are, if anything, a subset of non-const objects?

Comment: @NathanOliver Simply incorrect. References have types of *reference to objects*, which are normatively defined in ISO C++ [basic.compound].

Comment: `const int` or `const int&` are both subtypes of `int` due to the single-direction adjustment rules in [expr.type]. (For semantics on the value side, see also lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.)
Reference qualifiers are generally contravarint to *cv*-qualifiers except at the return type of function types, where they are covariant.

Comment: @FrankHB: "*References have types of reference to objects*" Irrelevant. If you have a variable, and you make a reference to that variable, you can use the reference in virtually identical circumstances with identical behavior as the original variable being referenced. The primary exceptions to this involve `return/throw <expr>`, where if the expression is the variable itself, any copy/move operation can be elided, while that doesn't work for references. There may be some `decltype` gymnastics as well.

Comment: @NicolBolas A declared reference itself *is* a variable, distinct to the object it refers to. (And the object is not necessarily a variable because it can be introduced without a declaration.) Type of an entity is not the same of type of an expression. For a reference, it does have the type specified in its declaration, that is the reference type, not the type of the object it refers to.

Comment: As per [expr.type], the further adjustment works only in the context where expressions are concerned. And more specifically, it is only effective on *evaluated operands* because other cases like the operands of `decltype` obey more specialized rules and they make the adjustment conceptually redundant.

Comment: The key point here is that the process of the adjustment itself is a non-trivial semantic function in the meta level (the operational semantics of the typing judgement). When talking about the relationship between types of the expressions, the term before the adjustment and the term after the adjustment are not identical. OTOH, the subtyping relationship lives in both sides: whether there are the adjustment, the criteria of subtyping always remain the same. However, the adjustment actually reduces too much type information, so it is not worth the analysis for practical reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could consider CV-qualifiers to be "subtypes" under some definition, references are not. `const T t = some_t;` creates a new object of type `T` declared as `const`. You might think of it as creating a new `const T`, but either way, you are creating a new object whose value conceptually is a copy of an existing one.

`T &t = some_t;` does not create a new object. It creates a *reference* to an existing object. That is a fundamentally different kind of thing in C++. References are not objects; the language is very clear about that. And it serves no useful purpose to think of a reference as a "subtype".

Comment: To lend further credence it even states that it is unspecified if a reference even occupies any space while any other "object" is required to take up at least one byte (baring EBO, but you are not treating it as a distinct object in that case)

Comment: It is true that reference types are not object types. However, this fact has nothing to do with how subtype desciplines work.

Answer (score 0):

> `int` being a subtype of `const int`

Well, it's not very clear what you're asking about, but it seems to be quite the other way round, since other forms of *subtyping* `int` using `const` or `volatile` would add more constraints than the original (value) type.

Comment: An `int` can be used safely where a `const int` is expected, not the contrary.

Comment: @Vincent perhaps you could explain in the question how "`int` is a (sub)type of `const int`"?  I seem to be one of several who see only the reverse.

Comment: @Vincent Right, so an `int` is the more general case. Anyway,  what you say is not really true. For example `char a[x];` - here `x` cannot be an `int`, it must be a `const int`.